# How to upload several images with httpPost?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I want to upload images using http post but my code causes a 500 error.

One file is ok, but two files or more files cause a 500 error.

Is it server problem? I don't know why.

Here is my upload code part:

```
-(void)sendImageByPost:(NSMutableArray *)images{
//create request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

//Set Params
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:60];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//Create boundary, it can be anything
NSString *boundary = @"------VohpleBoundary4QuqLuM1cE5lMwCy";

// set Content-Type in HTTP header
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

// post body
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

NSString *FileParamConstant = @"imageParamName";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDate *now;
NSString *date;
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddhhmmss"];


[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

for(UIImage * image in images){
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
    now = [NSDate date];
    date = [formatter stringFromDate:now];

    //Assuming data is not nil we add this to the multipart form
    if (imageData)
    {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", FileParamConstant, date] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:imageData];
    }
}


[body appendData:[@"Content-Type:image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
//Close off the request with the boundary
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// setting the body of the post to the request
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// set URL
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://52.68.115.148/api/fileupload"]];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

                           NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;

                           if ([httpResponse statusCode] == 201) {

                               NSLog(@"success");
                           }
                           else{
                               NSLog(@"fail");
                               NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [httpResponse statusCode]]);
                           }

                       }];
}
```

Comment: The 500 error you are getting is a internal server error. You will have to talk to the server developer because it is a server error.

Comment: Check on server if the multiple images in the attachment is handled or not. Also, you need different file name for every image or attachment to upload. Now, you are using same key or name to upload or attach all images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your request's body is not correct multipart/form-data.

You forgot boundary after each image. Try to change

```
if (imageData)
    {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", FileParamConstant, date] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:imageData];
    }
```

to

```
if (imageData)
    {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", FileParamConstant, date] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:imageData];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    }
```